# How to access or calculate slippage from Uniswap-V3 trades on-chain?

Tags: blockchain, defi, trading

I know we can extract swapping information on a Uniswap V3 LP pool (for example - https://info.uniswap.org/#/polygon/pools/0xefa98fdf168f372e5e9e9b910fcdfd65856f3986). Is there a way to find out the amount of slippage each of these trades has experienced in execution? Is slippage information on-chain or can be derived somehow?

I browsed through the transaction information, but can't identify anything resembling slippage or could be used for slippage calculation.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to find out the amount of slippage each of these trades has experienced in execution?

[Slippage](https://tradingstrategy.ai/glossary/slippage) is defined as the difference between what the trader assumes will be the outcome of the trade and what is the actual outcome. The trader is using price information in some point of time to come up with the assumed price. Because these assumptions are made off-chain, it is not possible to determine what was the slippage purely on on-chain data.

However you can calculate [price impact](https://tradingstrategy.ai/glossary/price-impact) of each trade, because price impact is a function of available liquidity.